# MUI Datagrid open column filter directly from button in header

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

Is there a way to force filter button to always be visible in each column header no matter if filter is applied or not.
I tried doing it from `sx` prop like this

```
<DataGrid
    sx={{
      '.MuiDataGrid-iconButtonContainer': {
        visibility: 'visible',
      },
      '.MuiDataGrid-filterIcon': {
        opacity: 'inherit !important',
      },
    }}
```

But it works only with sortIcon. Filter icon does not appear in DOM unless there is a filter for this column therefore it's not possible to access its styles

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: You can check out a solution provided by MUI team
https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/9464

Answer (score 0):

By this, you can force the filter button to always be visible in each column header.

```
<DataGrid
sx={{
  '.MuiDataGrid-iconButtonContainer': {
    visibility: 'visible,'
  },
  '.MuiDataGrid-menuIcon': {
    visibility: 'visible !important',
  },
}}
```

I hope in this way you can achieve it.